# Wave Operators: Cook

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Given Hilbert spaces $\mathcal{H}_0$ and $\mathcal{H}$.

Consider Hamiltonians:
$$H_\#:\mathcal{D}(H_\#)\to\mathcal{H}_\#:\quad H_\#=H_\#^*$$

Denote their evolutions:
$$U_\#(t)^*=U_\#(-t)=U_\#(t)^{-1}$$

Regard an operator:
$$J:\mathcal{H}_0\to\mathcal{H}:\quad\|J\|<\infty$$

Suppose invariance:
$$J\mathcal{D}H_0^2\subseteq\mathcal{D}H^2$$

And the estimate:
$$\int_0^\infty\|\{HJ-JH_0\}U_0(s)\varphi\|\mathrm{d}s<\infty\quad(\varphi\in\mathcal{D}H_0^2)$$

> Then the limit exists:
>   $$\Omega\varphi:=\lim_{t\to\infty}U(t)^*JU_0(t)\varphi\quad(\varphi\in\mathcal{H})$$

How can I prove this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Meanwhile I got it...*

Define the function:
$$\varphi\in\mathcal{D}H_0^2:\quad\omega(t):=U(t)^*JU_0(t)\varphi$$

Its derivatives are:
$$\omega'(t)=U(t)i\{HJ-JH_0\}U_0(t)\varphi$$
$$\omega''(t)=U(t)i^2\{H^2J-2HJH_0+JH_0^2\}U_0(t)\varphi$$

By Pettis' criterion:*
$$\omega''\in\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{H})\implies\omega'\in\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{H})\implies\omega'\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{H})$$

And it is integrable:
$$\int_0^\infty\|\omega'(s)\|\mathrm{d}s=\int_0^\infty\|\{HJ-JH_0\}U_0(s)\varphi\|\mathrm{d}s<\infty$$

By fundamental theorem:
$$U(t)^*JU_0(t)\varphi-J\varphi=\omega(t)-\omega(0)=\int_0^t\omega'(s)\mathrm{d}s$$

By dominated convergence:
$$\|U(t')^*JU_0(t')\varphi-U(t)^*JU_0(t)\varphi\|=\|\int_t^{t'}\omega'(s)\mathrm{d}s\|\stackrel{t,t'\to\infty}{\to}0$$

But the domain is dense:
$$\overline{\mathcal{D}H_0^2}\supseteq\overline{\bigcup_{R>0}\mathcal{R}E(B_R)}=\mathcal{H}_0$$

Concluding the assertion.